# Object Oriented Design - C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have a scenario with 4 classes like,

```
class SuperGroup,
class Group,
class SubGroup,
class MicroGroup,
```

Here, SuperGroup will contain a list of Groups, and a Group will contain a list of SubGroups and so on...

Now, I want to design my classes in a way that,
Groups can only be created by SuperGroups, and similarly SuperGroups could only create Groups, they cannot create SubGroups directly. Rather when they want a SubGroup, they have to create a Group, then by that object of Group, they could create subGroups.

The same conditions will also apply to < Group,SubGroups > , < SubGroups,MicroGroups > .

How could I achieve that in C#.

Comment: @NicholasKing I dont know how to search for this particular scenario in internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object Oriented Paradigm - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439653/object-oriented-paradigm-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want `createChild()` to be a public method of each class, with the actual child constructors protected or private?

Client code would then call the parent entity to create child entities, rather than being able to construct them directly.

Comment: I thougt of protected constructors but that required inheritance. And inheritance will create `is-a` releationship, but i want `has-many` releationship.

Comment: **Protected constructors don't require inheritance**, they prevent public access while not preventing future inheritance. You can use `private` but `protected` would be better in practice.

Comment: `getChildren()'` and `createChild()` would constitute the has-many Children relationship. Inheritance can't constitute a relationship between two entities/instances.. since it's between classes, not instances.

Comment: Now suppose my `SubGroup` has protected constructor , and client code(here `SuperGroup`) calls the `groupObj.createChild()` to create a `subGroup` object. But the problem is how `createChild()` will create the `subGroupObj`, since the SubGroup constructor is protected. Do I need to inherit the `SubGroup` in the class `Group` to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Put the classes together in their own Assembly and make the constructors of the classes you want to prevent created externally internal.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look online for inheritance and the Factory Pattern.
And yes, keep the constructors private.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple, Inherit Group from SuperGroup, create a method in Super group that would create createGroup()

then inherit SUbGroups from Group, similarly add method createSubGroup() in Group.
And so on. I hope u can make it further

Comment: Multi-level inheritance is not the answer. Commonality between the different entities, if exploited, would only be a single level of inheritance. 'NestableContainer' or 'NestableEntity' could be the common superclass, for example.

Comment: inheritance will create `is-a` releationship meaning every super-Group is a Group, meaning in my particular scenario "every accountHead will be a accountEntry". So, I dont want `is-a` releationship